# How to avoid waitForStarted with QProcess to stop GUI from freezing?

Tags: c++, qt, qprocess

I am running wscript with QProcess to run a VB Script that converts Excel files to tab delimited text files. The script runs fine and everything, but the GUI freezes and the user is unable to interact with it for a significant amount of time. Here is the code:

```
/* Create txt files and store paths */
for (int i = 0; i < excelFilepaths.size(); ++i) {    
    wscript->start("wscript.exe", QStringList() << vbs.fileName() << excelFilepaths.at(i) << newDir.absolutePath() + "/" + QString::number(i + 1));
    wscript->waitForFinished();
    payloadPaths.push_back(newDir.absolutePath() + "/" + QString::number(i + 1));
}
```

So whats going on is that I have multiple excel file paths and a QProcess allocated on the heap. This QProcess runs the VB Script that converts the excel files into text files and then stores the path of the new text file. This takes a long time (about 20 seconds for 4 excel files). During this time the GUI is frozen. I would like the user to be able to use parts of the GUI that don't interfere with the process.

Now I suspect that the cause of this issue is

```
QProcess::waitForFinished()
```

And I've read online about connecting the finished() and error() signals of QProcess to remove this problem. However I've been having difficulty doing so. I'm running this code as a method of  a class that inherits from QObject and containst the Q_OBJECT macro, so everything should be set. I just need some help putting the rest of the pieces together. How can I make it so my GUI does not freeze while QProcess is running? Please help.

Comment: *However I've been having difficulty doing so* What have you tried? What failed?

Comment: *"How can I make it so my GUI does not freeze while QProcess is running?"* - By *"connecting the finished() and error() signals of QProcess"* to local slots, and removing the synchronous `waitForFinished` call.

Comment: How do I connect those signals though? and How does this eliminate my problem? I think I would do something like connect(process, &QProcess::finished, this, &CustomClass::slotHere). Or I could get rid of the custom slot and do connect(process, &QProcess::finished, lambdaHere). An example would be very helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To quote the documentation at the section called [*Synchronous Process API*](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#synchronous-process-api):

> - `waitForStarted()` blocks until the process has started.
> - `waitForReadyRead()` blocks until new data is available for reading on the current read channel.
> - `waitForBytesWritten()` blocks until one payload of data has been written to the process.
> - `waitForFinished()` blocks until the process has finished.
>
> Calling these functions from the main thread (the thread that calls QApplication::exec()) may cause your user interface to freeze.

Keep that in mind. However you may overcome this issue using something like [that](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#finished):

```
connect(process, static_cast<void(QProcess::*)(int, QProcess::ExitStatus)>(&QProcess::finished),
[=](int exitCode, QProcess::ExitStatus exitStatus){ /* ... */ });
```

Note that there are some more [signals](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#signals) which may suite any desired purpose.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but with **QSerialPort**. However, i think the solution is the same. I couldn't find a way to have "serial->waitForReadyRead()" not freezing the GUI, so, I implemented my own function.

```
void Research::WaitSerial(int MilliSecondsToWait)
{
    QTime DieTime = QTime::currentTime().addMSecs(MilliSecondsToWait);
    flag = 0;
    while(QTime::currentTime() < DieTime && !flag)
    {
        QCoreApplication::processEvents(QEventLoop::AllEvents,100);
        if(BufferSerial != "")
        {
            flag++;
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, your problem is similar but not the same. Just change the `if`to have your "stopping condition". Hope this helps.

---

EDIT: This was not originally my ideia. I found it on a forum somewhere. So I don't take the credits.

Comment: Polling, as always, is only the second-best solution. Qt uses [signals & slots](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html) to drive its event-based framework.

Comment: Could you explain a bit of whats going on here? It seems to me that you are manually stalling the program while the QProcess runs. Is that correct?

Comment: @Dillydill123 Well, yes. I am doing exactly that. I just stall the program until the serial send something. In my case it is the same as `WaitForReadyRead`. I Don't know how to do it with signals and slots, sorry.

Comment: using `QCoreApplication::processEvents(QEventLoop::AllEvents,100);`makes so that the GUI don't freeze by processing all events of current thread. Allowing you to, for example, to move the window while it is waiting. As for the `QTime DieTime = QTime::currentTime().addMSecs(MilliSecondsToWait);`, that's just the amount of time it will be waiting. The rest is only MY stopping point. As said above, this is **NOT** the best option..... but is a quick and easy to understand one.